# Texture displacement map in real-time

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, displacement

I want to texture the displacement map and see the change in the viewport immediately.

I use the Displace Modifier.

I try Eevee and Cycles, in both cases, Blender doesn't update automatically viewport. I need to click any settings in Modifier Properties or Texture Properties. After that all ok.

Is possible to texture displacement map in real-time?

Comment: In blender 2.92, the default behaviour seems to be for the geometry generated by the Displace modifier to automatically update after each texture paint stroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly realtime but hitting Tab twice (goes into edit and back) after a stroke of texture painting will update the geometry right away.

[image]

Comment: I find that [tabbing] between Edit and other modes doesn't update the texture or displacement, but switching between Material Preview and back to Render Preview does.  Using 3.0.0 release candidate